# How would the linux kernel find all IRQs registered to mice?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling, input-devices

I am new to kernel hacking and I am wanting to know if there is a way to find all IRQs that HID mice drivers have registered with the kernel.

Edit** I need to know how find the correct irq given only the possible input_values.
The other question that was said to be duplicate was concerned with obtaining the handler given the irq, which is not what I'm looking for; I am actually looking for the irq itself.

Comment: Don't make dups https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361894/getting-access-to-the-input-handler-from-the-irq-lane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting access to the input handler from the IRQ lane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361894/getting-access-to-the-input-handler-from-the-irq-lane)

Comment: That is not even the same question.